# No access to YT channel

Tags: youtube

The company I work for has a YT channel, it contains some videos they made but they have no clue who is the admin. Nobody can see it at [www.myaccount.google.com/brandaccounts](http://www.myaccount.google.com/brandaccounts) or can access it with there Google account. Is there a way to regain access? Youtube support hasn't the right answer (or I'm not looking at the right questions). Every answer assumes I can access the channel.

I contacted Google Workspace support but they can't help. I can't find a solution at the support pages of YT. We all checked if we can access the channel with our account and we all checked the brand accounts section.